# Magento2 model is not getting overriden?

Tags: overrides, model, magento-2.1

I want to override the model class `vendor/magento/module-grouped-product/Model/Product/Type/Grouped.php` via a custom module.

My `Test/Kit/etc/di.xml` is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\GroupedProduct\Model\Product\Type\Grouped" type="Test\Kit\Model\Rewrite\Product\Type\Grouped" />
</config>
```

And the model class is as belows.

```
app/code/Test/Kit/Model/Rewrite/GroupedProduct/Product/Type/Grouped.php


namespace Test\Kit\Model\Rewrite\Product\Type;

class Grouped extends \Magento\GroupedProduct\Model\Product\Type\Grouped
{
    /**
     * Retrieve array of associated products
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAssociatedProducts($product)
    {
        if (!$product->hasData($this->_keyAssociatedProducts)) {
            $associatedProducts = [];

            $this->setSaleableStatus($product);

            $collection = $this->getAssociatedProductCollection(
                $product
            )->addAttributeToSelect(
                ['name', 'price',  'special_price', 'special_from_date', 'special_to_date']
            );
//                ->addFilterByRequiredOptions()->setPositionOrder()->addStoreFilter(
//                $this->getStoreFilter($product)
//            )->addAttributeToFilter(
//                'status',
//                ['in' => $this->getStatusFilters($product)]
//            );

            foreach ($collection as $item) {
                $associatedProducts[] = $item;
            }

            $product->setData($this->_keyAssociatedProducts, $associatedProducts);
        }
        return $product->getData($this->_keyAssociatedProducts);
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Below fix worked.

Changed the `di.xml` file path as below. Putting it under an **adminhtml** folder did the trick.

```
app/code/Netstarter/KitGrouped/etc/adminhtml/di.xml
```

It seems Magento2 expects some di.xml files to be reside inside etc or etc/adminhtml or etc/frontend directories based on different occasions. Hope this might be useful for someone, so no need to struggle with override classes anymore :)